# Other Halo spinners can't load

Tags: python

Recently, I just discovered a third-party module named `halo`, which allows you to create and use some pretty cool loading icons. However, when I was testing it, it didn't load the spinner I wanted. This is my code:

```
import halo
import time

spinner = halo.Halo(text='Testing...', spinner='dots')
spinner.start()
time.sleep(10)
spinner.stop()
```

I don't think anything is wrong with the code, but halo won't load the dots. Instead, it loads this:

```
/ Testing...
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the code a ways, there's this check:

```
if is_supported():
    if all([is_text_type(spinner), spinner in Spinners.__members__]):
        return Spinners[spinner].value
    else:
        return default_spinner
else:
    return Spinners["line"].value
```

And `is_supported` is:

```
def is_supported():
    """Check whether operating system supports main symbols or not.

    Returns
    -------
    boolean
        Whether operating system supports main symbols or not
    """

    os_arch = platform.system()

    if os_arch != 'Windows':
        return True

    return False
```

You can see that if `is_supported` returns False, is defaults to `Spinners["line"].value`, which means that this library really only works on non-Windows systems.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there an alternative to Halo that can be run on Windows?

Comment: @TheCodingNoob-Amateur-Pro No clue unfortunately. I had never even heard of this library until I saw your question.